# Store files from a filelist in tarball on IBM i - shell

Tags: shell, tar, ibm-midrange, filelist

I want to create a tarfile from a filelist.
The filelist has two rows

```
log1.dat
log2.dat
```

The shell script looks like:

```
cd /temp/temp1 
tar -cvf test.tar -L inp.txt
```

All files are stored in the dir `temp/temp1`.
The qshell throws an error:

```
no file or directory with the name inp.txt
```

but the file is there and named inp.txt.

The `test.tar` is created and the `inp.txt` is stored in the archive.
I don't want to put the `inp.txt` in the tarball - I want to store the files listed in the `inp.txt`.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the [PASE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzalf/rzalfintro.htm) `tar` utility accepts `[ -L InputList ]` as a parameter.

```
Usage: tar -{c|r|t|u|x} [ -BdDEFhilmopRUsvw ] [ -Number ] [ -f TarFile ]            
         [ -b Blocks ] [ -S [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ]           
         [ -L InputList ] [-X ExcludeFile] [ -N Blocks ] [ -C Directory ] File ...

Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x} [ bBdDEfFhilLXmNopRsSUvw[0-9] ] ]                            
         [ Blocks ] [ TarFile ] [ InputList ] [ ExcludeFile ]                     
         [ [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ] [-C Directory ] File ...
```

Qualify the path to the utility to use the PASE version:

```
/qopensys/usr/bin/tar -cvf test.tar -L inp.txt
```